# How to call angular method inside jQuery mouseover?

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, angular8, mouseover

I am using Angular 8. I am reading a svg file and find elements with style has `stroke:none`. Then I am going to open a dialog box whenever someone hovers over that element.

I need to open Angular Material dialog box inside jQuery mouseover. This alert is working but `this.openDialog()` is not working.

This gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: component.openDialog is not a function

*main.component.ts*

```
   openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogBoxComponent, {
      height: '100px',
      width: '450px',
    });
  }

myfunction() {
    const mySVG: any = document.getElementById('svg-object');
    mySVG.addEventListener('load',() => {
      svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;

      $(svgDoc).find('path').css('fill','fill-opacity','fill-rule','stroke').each(function() {
        const style = $(this).attr('style');

        if($(this).attr('style').includes('stroke:none')) {
          const component = this;
          $(this).mouseover(() => {
               component.openDialog();
               alert('HELLO');
          });
        }
      });
    }, false);
}
```

*DialogBoxComponent.ts*

```
  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MainComponent>) {
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
```

*DialogBoxComponent.html*

```
<h3 mat-dialog-title>TOPIC</h3>
<div class="container">
  <div class="device-config-main-container d-flex flex-column">
  </div>
  <div mat-dialog-actions>
    <button mat-button mat-dialog-close (click)="onNoClick()">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Take const component=this; line to first line of function

Comment: You 're welcome :) your this was referance to mySVG.addEventListener. that is why you get that error .

Comment: @pc_coder this dialog box is not closing.. Any idea why?

Comment: If you create demo in stackblitz , it can help me to understand problem

Comment: @pc_coder Since I'm unable to share my svg file I updated this question with the added code..

Comment: @pc_coder I called the openDialog() method for a div id in ngOnInit and it is closing successfully...
I cannot understand why it is not closing when I call openDialog() in the eventListener